# How can I get a callback from an async disk read in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a GetPhoto method to get a photo from disk:

```
public async Task<IFile> GetPhoto(string fileName)
{
    var localStorage = FileSystem.Current.LocalStorage;
    var folderExists = await localStorage.CheckExistsAsync(PhotosFolder);

    if (!folderExists.Equals(ExistenceCheckResult.FolderExists))
    {
        return null;
    }

    var localStorageFolder = await localStorage.GetFolderAsync(PhotosFolder);
    var fileExists = await localStorageFolder.CheckExistsAsync(fileName);

    if (!fileExists.Equals(ExistenceCheckResult.FileExists))
    {
        return null;
    }

    return await localStorageFolder.GetFileAsync(fileName);

}
```

An another one that calls GetPhoto with a specific photo:

```
public async Task<ImageSource> ProfileImageSource()
{
    var file = await StorageHelper.Current.GetPhoto("profile_picture.jpg");
    if (file == null)
    {
        return ImageSource.FromFile("profile_placeholder.png");
    }

    var stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccess.Read);
    stream.Close();
    return ImageSource.FromStream(() => stream);

}
```

These run asynchronous.

Then, I have a SetTableView method. This method gets the profile image to be presented in the table view.

```
 private async void SetTableView()
 {
  var profileImageSource = await ProfileImageSource();

  Content = new TableView
  {
     HasUnevenRows = true,
     Intent = TableIntent.Menu,
     Root = new TableRoot()
     {
        new TableSection()
         {
            new ProfileCell(profileImageSource, "Casa de Férias", HandleProfileCellTap())
         }
     }
   };
}
```

However, when the TableView is built the image source hasn’t yet completely loaded the image from the stream, causing me a crash, saying that data cannot be null.

How can I tell TableView to only build when my ImageSource is ready?

Thank you

Comment: Is it xamarin.forms or Android ? 
How about if you do not update the ImageSource before the image is ready? by that I mean the string tha represent the image source . Could you share the ViewModel please and the TabelView please ?

Comment: It's Xamarin.Forms. How would I update it after the image is ready? Could you elaborate? there is no ViewModel. I do have a StorageHelper and the code for my HomePage.xaml.cs

Comment: I need more information about your code , it all depends on how you the image , if it is bound  to a viewmodel or not , or even if this is a xamarin.forms or just Xamarin.Android

Comment: Ok can you share the TabelView Code ?

Comment: I see it is not Xaml .

Comment: I have :) It's in the question inside the SetTableVIew() method.

Comment: did it ever work before ? like for smaller images ?

Comment: Yes, it did. In a device and for small images it works most of the time. However if it takes just a bit longer to load the file it crashes.

Comment: are you sure it is because of the time and not because of memory ?

Comment: Anotherway to do this , is to store the photo somewhere online , and then you just refer to it, and it would work unless you need that for offline .

Comment: It looks like you close stream before you read. stream.Close();
    return ImageSource.FromStream(() => stream);

Comment: I was really looking forward to that suggestion.. but no. It still has the same problem. I'm trying to get access to something that doesn't exist yet.